# I am getting the error in my flutter project when implementing google sign in

Tags: android, flutter, google-signin

Here I have implemented google login. i have used the **google_sign_in 4.1.4** please help me to find out where am i doing mistake or missing something.
Thanks in advance..!!

this error 
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/LifecycleEventObserver;
I/zygote64(27656):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.Class.newInstance() (Class.java:-2)

```
 onTap: () async{

                            _signIn(context)
                                .then((FirebaseUser user) => print(user))
                                .catchError((e) => print(e));

                          },
```

```
 final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();

  Future<FirebaseUser> _signIn(BuildContext context) async{
    GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn(); //crash on this line
    GoogleSignInAuthentication gSA = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
    final AuthCredential  credential  = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken: gSA.idToken, accessToken: gSA.accessToken);
    final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    final FirebaseUser userDetails = authResult.user;
    ProviderDetails providerInfo = new ProviderDetails(userDetails.providerId);
    List<ProviderDetails> providerData = new List<ProviderDetails>();
    providerData.add(providerInfo);

    UserDetails details = new UserDetails(
      userDetails.providerId,
      userDetails.displayName,
      userDetails.photoUrl,
      userDetails.email,
      providerData,
    );

 Navigator.push(
      context,
      new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => new ChooseCollegeScreen(),
      ),
    );

    return userDetails;
}
```

here is my error log=========>

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/LifecycleEventObserver;
I/zygote64(27656):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.Class.newInstance() (Class.java:-2)
I/zygote64(27656):   at android.app.Activity android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, android.content.Intent) (Instrumentation.java:1175)
I/zygote64(27656):   at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2708)
I/zygote64(27656):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2895)
I/zygote64(27656):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
I/zygote64(27656):   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1616)
I/zygote64(27656):   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
I/zygote64(27656):   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:176)
I/zygote64(27656):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6651)
I/zygote64(27656):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
I/zygote64(27656):   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:547)
I/zygote64(27656):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:824)
I/zygote64(27656): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleEventObserver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/moon.campushaat.com-_doLzLlPm2QzmtHCYUYAfg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/moon.campushaat.com-_doLzLlPm2QzmtHCYUYAfg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/moon.campushaat.com-_doLzLlPm2QzmtHCYUYAfg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
I/zygote64(27656):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
I/zygote64(27656):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
I/zygote64(27656):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
I/zygote64(27656):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.Class.newInstance() (Class.java:-2)
I/zygote64(27656):   at android.app.Activity android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, android.content.Intent) (Instrumentation.java:1175)
I/zygote64(27656):   at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2708)
I/zygote64(27656):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2895)
I/zygote64(27656):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
I/zygote64(27656):   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1616)
I/zygote64(27656):   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
I/zygote64(27656):   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:176)
I/zygote64(27656):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6651)
I/zygote64(27656):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
I/zygote64(27656):   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:547)
I/zygote64(27656):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

Comment: What version of Android platform is on your device or emulator?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your app [migrated to `androidx`](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration#how-do-i-migrate-my-existing-app-plugin-or-host-editable-module-project-to-androidx).
(`gradle.properties` file contains line `android.useAndroidX=true`)

Also this error may be related to apk-file size (over 64K limit) on old Android devices (API < 21). Either change `minSdkVersion` to 21+, or [configure your app for multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle).

In module-level `build.gradle` file add the `multidex` library as a dependency:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

Comment: migration to androidX is most likely cause

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've resolved this, but here is how I fixed a similar issue.

1. Added the multidex dependency in the build.gradle(app) file of the android part.

   ```
    dependencies {
        ...
        implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    }
   ```
2. Also add this line of code in the same build.gradle file.

   ```
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
   ```
3. Extend the FlutterApplication class and enable the MultiDex class there.

   ```
    class MyFlutterApp: FlutterApplication() {
        override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
            super.attachBaseContext(base)
            MultiDex.install(this)
        }
    }
   ```
4. Then add the class to your manifest.

   ```
    <application
        android:name=".MyFlutterApp"
        ...
    </application>
   ```

This should fix your issue.